# JSTL foreach var sending to jsp/servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I want to know a method how can I send 1 specified item for JSTL's foreach to other JSP or servlet, to print detailed info about that item.

Giving followin code:

```
    <c:forEach var="note" items="${notes}">
        <tr>
            <td>${note.getTitle()}</td>
            <td>${note.getRealDate()}</td>
            <td>${note.getUserDate()}</td>
            <td>
                <form action="showdetails.jsp">
                    <input type="submit" value="show details" name="details" />
                </form> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

I need to replace my form, or remake it, to get something that does the job, and I'm out of ideas...

ah, btw. Note has method shown above + `showDetails()` with `String` return. And I want to display them all, or just do `String all = note.toString();` in jsp/servlet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass an identifier as request parameter and change the URL to be a servlet one. If you insist to use a submit button, pass the identifier as a hidden input field:

```html
<form action="showdetails">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${note.id}" />
    <input type="submit" name="details" value="show details" />
</form>
```

In the servlet which is mapped on an URL pattern of `/showdetails` just do the following job in `doGet()` method:

```java
String id = request.getParameter("id");
Note note = noteService.find(id);
request.setAttribute("note", note);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/showdetails.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

In the `showdetails.jsp` you can then use `${note}` to access the selected `Note`.

Exactly the above servlet is also useable when you use a link instead as Bozho suggests, with only one little difference, in the servlet you're able to preprocess the request (to find and prepare the right `Note` object for display).

```html
<a href="showdetails?id=${note.id}">show details</a>
```

#### See also:

- [Our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a `<form>`. Just add a link, using a field that uniquely identifies the item:

```
<a href="showdetails.jsp?noteId=${note.id}">show details</a>
```

Comment: how can I add second (add more) parameter to that link? ... I tried to make it work with id only, but i can't get so simply list of my objects in that JSP without giving sesion to

Comment: you can add anything, but you shouldn't need to. I don't see your problem, so I can't help more.

Comment: I just ask how to make validate link to split parameters in it <ashamed> something like this `?title=${note.getTitle()}?realDate=${note.getRealDate()}?userDate=${note.getUserDate()}?content=${note.getContent()}">show details` doesn't work :) it makes one big, useless parameter